# Snakemake and SLURM -unable to use it with with --cluster

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to automate some of my previous bash scripts with snakemake. Below is one of the recipe I created:

```
import os
shell.executable("/bin/bash")

workdir: "/proj/uppstore2018136/publication/jupyterNotebooks"

ENSEMBL_RELEASE='94'
ENSEMBL_GRCm38_BASE='ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-'+ENSEMBL_RELEASE+'/fasta/mus_musculus/dna'
ENSEMBL_GRCm38_GTF_BASE='ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-'+ENSEMBL_RELEASE+'/gtf/mus_musculus'
GTF_FILE='Mus_musculus.GRCm38.'+ENSEMBL_RELEASE+'.gtf'

rule all:
    input:
        "genome/genome.fa",
        "genome/"+GTF_FILE,
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.1.bt2",
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.2.bt2",
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.3.bt2",
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.4.bt2",
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.rev1.bt2",
        "indexes/bowtie2/reference.rev2.bt2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.1.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.2.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.3.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.4.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.5.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.6.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.7.ht2",
        "indexes/hisat2/reference.8.ht2"

rule getGenome:
    output:
        output1="genome/genome.fa",
        output2="genome/"+GTF_FILE
    shell:
           '''
           curl -o genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna.primary_assembly.fa.gz {ENSEMBL_GRCm38_BASE}/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna.primary_assembly.fa.gz
           gunzip genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna.primary_assembly.fa.gz
           mv genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna.primary_assembly.fa genome/genome.fa
           curl -o genome/{GTF_FILE}.gz {ENSEMBL_GRCm38_GTF_BASE}/{GTF_FILE}.gz
           gunzip genome/{GTF_FILE}.gz
           '''

rule bowtie2Build:
    input: "genome/genome.fa"
    params:
        basename="indexes/bowtie2/reference"
    output:
        output1="indexes/bowtie2/reference.1.bt2",
        output2="indexes/bowtie2/reference.2.bt2",
        output3="indexes/bowtie2/reference.3.bt2",
        output4="indexes/bowtie2/reference.4.bt2",
        outputrev1="indexes/bowtie2/reference.rev1.bt2",
        outputrev2="indexes/bowtie2/reference.rev2.bt2"
    threads: 20
    shell: 
        '''
        module load bowtie2
        bowtie2-build --threads {threads} {input} {params.basename}
        '''

rule hisat2Build:
    input: "genome/genome.fa",
        "genome/"+GTF_FILE 
    params:
        basename="indexes/hisat2/reference"
    output:
        output1="indexes/hisat2/reference.1.ht2",
        output2="indexes/hisat2/reference.2.ht2",
        output3="indexes/hisat2/reference.3.ht2",
        output4="indexes/hisat2/reference.4.ht2",
        output5="indexes/hisat2/reference.5.ht2",
        output6="indexes/hisat2/reference.6.ht2",
        output7="indexes/hisat2/reference.7.ht2",
        output8="indexes/hisat2/reference.8.ht2",
    threads: 20
    shell: 
        '''
        module load HISAT2
        hisat2_extract_splice_sites.py genome/{GTF_FILE} > genome/genome.ss
        hisat2_extract_exons.py genome/{GTF_FILE} > genome/genome.exon
        hisat2-build -f -p {threads} {input} --ss genome/genome.ss --exon genome/genome.exon {params.basename}
        rm genome/genome.ss
        rm genome/genome.exon
        '''

rule clean:
    shell:
        '''
        rm genome/*
        rm indexes/bowtie2/*
        rm indexes/hisat2/*
        '''
```

And this is my driver script which I'm submitting as a job itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

module load snakemake

snakemake --jobs 1 --local-cores 20 --cluster-config /crex/proj/uppstore2018136/publication/jupyterNotebooks/recipes/cluster.json --latency-wait 120 --max-jobs-per-second 1 -c "sbatch -A {cluster.account} -p {cluster.partition} -n {-cluster.n} -t {cluster.time} -C {cluster.C}" -s indexMake
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 1
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   bowtie2Build
    1   getGenome
    1   hisat2Build
    4

rule getGenome:
    output: genome/genome.fa, genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.94.gtf
    jobid: 2

RuleException in line 30 of /crex/proj/uppstore2018136/publication/jupyterNotebooks/recipes/indexMake:
NameError: The name '-cluster' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}

}
```

I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong here ? Is there a conflict with variables or there is something wrong with the snakemake version I'm using (4.5.0).

Comment: (vote to leave open) I know that Snakemake can be used for non-bioinformatics problems. But in practice it is used solely by bioinfo community therefore I think debugging snakefiles is appropriate for this Q&A site.

Comment: (vote to close) The official Snakemake docs point folks to Stack Overflow. I suggest we use StackExchange's migrate mechanism to send generic Snakemake questions to SO to keep it all in one place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow (although I lack the reputation to initiate the migration).

Comment: @DanielStandage it does seem to be aimed primarily at bioinformaticians, and is indeed a tool commonly used by the community, so it seems reasonable that we should support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your submission script you have `-n {-cluster.n}`, hence the error from snakemake I guess. Are you sure it is not a typo and it should be `-n {cluster.n}` instead?

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the error. I'm not sure how it crept in - working on Sundays is not that productive -